# Generate all possible combinations of the elements of some vectors (Cartesian product)

Tags: matlab, combinatorics, cartesian-product

I would like to generate all the possible combinations of the elements of a given number of vectors.

For example, for `[1 2]`, `[1 2]` and `[4 5]` I want to generate the elements:

`[1 1 4; 1 1 5; 1 2 4; 1 2 5; 2 1 4; 2 1 5; 2 2 4; 2 2 5]`

The problem is that I don't know the number of vectors for which I need to calculate the combinations. There might be 3 as in this case, or there may be 10, and I need a *generalization*. Can you please help me to this in MATLAB? Is there already a predefined function that can do this task?

Comment: what you are looking for is called the 'cartesian product' of the vectors.  You may have some luck googling for that.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try [ALLCOMB](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/10064) function at FileExchange.

If you store you vectors in a cell array, you can run it like this:

```
a = {[1 2], [1 2], [4 5]};
allcomb(a{:})
ans =

     1     1     4
     1     1     5
     1     2     4
     1     2     5
     2     1     4
     2     1     5
     2     2     4
     2     2     5
```

Comment: Note that `ALLCOMB` uses `NDGRID` in essentially the same way as in Amro's answer, with error-proofing on top.

Answer (score 53):

Consider this solution using the [NDGRID](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/ndgrid.html) function:

```
sets = {[1 2], [1 2], [4 5]};
[x y z] = ndgrid(sets{:});
cartProd = [x(:) y(:) z(:)];

cartProd =
     1     1     4
     2     1     4
     1     2     4
     2     2     4
     1     1     5
     2     1     5
     1     2     5
     2     2     5
```

Or if you want a general solution for any number of sets (without having to create the variables manually), use this function definition:

```
function result = cartesianProduct(sets)
    c = cell(1, numel(sets));
    [c{:}] = ndgrid( sets{:} );
    result = cell2mat( cellfun(@(v)v(:), c, 'UniformOutput',false) );
end
```

---

Note that if you prefer, you can sort the results:

```
cartProd = sortrows(cartProd, 1:numel(sets));
```

Also, the code above does not check if the sets have no duplicate values (ex: `{[1 1] [1 2] [4 5]}`). Add this one line if you want to:

```
sets = cellfun(@unique, sets, 'UniformOutput',false);
```

Answer (score 14):

This late answers provides two additional solutions, where the second is *the solution* (in my opinion) and an improvement on Amro's answer solution with `ndgrid` by applying MATLAB's powerful comma-separated lists instead of cell arrays for high performance,

1. If you have the Neural Network Toolbox: use [`combvec`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/nnet/ref/combvec.html)
2. If you do *not* have the toolbox, as is usually the case: below is another way to generalize the Cartesian product for any number of sets.

Just as Amro did in his answer, the comma-separated lists syntax (`v{:}`) supplies both the inputs and outputs of `ndgrid`. The difference (fourth line) is that it avoids `cellfun` and `cell2mat` by applying comma-separated lists, again, now as the inputs to `cat`:

```
N = numel(a);
v = cell(N,1);
[v{:}] = ndgrid(a{:});
res = reshape(cat(N+1,v{:}),[],N);
```

The use of `cat` and `reshape` cuts execution time almost in half. This approach was demonstrated in [my answer to an different question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19991829/2778484), and [more formally by Luis Mendo](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21895335/2778484).

Comment: THIS is the way to go in my opinion. Noticed that it can easily be extended to get all the permutation of length `m` for a vector of length `n` with: `[v{1:m}] = ndgrid(1:n);` and `res = reshape(cat(m+1,v{:}),[],m)`

Answer (score 1):

Since MATLAB 2023a you can use the [`combinations`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/combinations.html) function, which supports vectors, matrices, cell arrays, and mixtures thereof:

```matlab
>> combinations([1 2], [1 2], [4 5])

ans =

  8×3 table

    Var1    Var2    Var3
    ____    ____    ____

     1       1       4  
     1       1       5  
     1       2       4  
     1       2       5  
     2       1       4  
     2       1       5  
     2       2       4  
     2       2       5
```

The output is in the form of a [table](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/tables.html), which supports mixed types. If your outputs need only a single type, you can convert the output to a matrix using [`table2array`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/table2array.html):

```matlab
>> table2array(combinations([1 2], [1 2], [4 5]))

ans =

     1     1     4
     1     1     5
     1     2     4
     1     2     5
     2     1     4
     2     1     5
     2     2     4
     2     2     5
```

For what it's worth, I have written a shim that emulates the behaviour of `combinations` in older versions of MATLAB (down to version 2013b), including support for mixed types:

```matlab
function grid = combinations(varargin)
    grid = cell(nargin, 1);
    [grid{:}] = ndgrid(varargin{:});

    combos = cellfun(@(it) it(:), grid, 'UniformOutput', false)';
    combos = table(combos{:});
end
```

Answer (score 0):

we can also use the 'combvec' instruction in matlab

```
    no_inp=3 % number of inputs we want...in this case we have 3 inputs                  
    a=[1 2 3]
    b=[1 2 3]
    c=[1 2 3]

    pre_final=combvec(c,b,a)';
    final=zeros(size(pre_final));

    for i=1:no_inp
    final(:,i)=pre_final(:,no_inp-i+1);
    end
    final
```

Hope it helps.
Good luck.