# Sequence generation of two vectors in matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, combinations, combinatorics, cartesian-product

Say, I have two vectors `[A B C]` and `[E F G]`

Now, I want a matrix like this below:

```
[A B C; E F G ;  A F G; A F C; E B C; E B G]
```

Comment: Please provide some more details, and examples of what have you tried so far.

Comment: What class are A, B, ...? Doubles, chars,...? Also, are they scalar?

Comment: it looks like you are doing the *cartesian product* (although you are missing some combinations: ABG, EFC). See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4165859/matlab-generate-all-possible-combinations-of-the-elements-of-some-vectors

Comment: here is another related question: [MATLAB: Combinations of an arbitrary number of cell arrays](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8492277/97160)

Comment: From the example it's hard to tell what you want. You should explain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the [same code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4169488/97160) I mentioned for [Cartesian product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product), adapted to work on sets of strings instead of numeric data:

```
sets = {{'A' 'E'};   % first position
        {'B' 'F'};   % second position
        {'C' 'G'}};  % third position

[val,~,idx] = cellfun(@unique, sets, 'Uniform',false);
indices = cell(numel(idx),1);
[indices{:}] = ndgrid(idx{:});
cartProd = cellfun(@(ind,v) v(ind(:)), indices, val, 'Uniform',false);
cartProd = vertcat(cartProd{:})';
```

This will work for any number of sets, each with any number of elements.

The resulting combinations for the example above (one per row):

```
>> cartProd
cartProd = 
    'A'    'B'    'C'
    'E'    'B'    'C'
    'A'    'F'    'C'
    'E'    'F'    'C'
    'A'    'B'    'G'
    'E'    'B'    'G'
    'A'    'F'    'G'
    'E'    'F'    'G'
```