# How to generate all pairs from two vectors in MATLAB using vectorised code?

Tags: matlab, combinations

More than once now I have needed to generate all possible pairs of two vectors in MATLAB which I do with for loops which take up a fair few lines of code i.e.

```
vec1 = 1:4;
vec2 = 1:3;
i = 0;
pairs = zeros([4*3 2]);
for val1 = vec1
    for val2 = vec2
         i = i + 1;
         pairs(i,1) = val1;
         pairs(i,2) = val2;
    end
end
```

Generates ...

```
1 1
1 2
1 3
2 1
2 2
2 3
3 1
3 2
3 3
4 1 
4 2
4 3
```

There must be a better way to do this which is more MATLAB'esque?

n.b. `nchoosek` does not do the reversed pairs which is what I need (i.e. `2 1` as well as `1 2`), I can't just reverse and append the `nchoosek` output because the symmetric pairs will be included twice.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Matlab - Generate all possible combinations of the elements of some vectors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4165859/matlab-generate-all-possible-combinations-of-the-elements-of-some-vectors)

Answer (score 97, accepted):

Try

```
[p,q] = meshgrid(vec1, vec2);
pairs = [p(:) q(:)];
```

See the [MESHGRID documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/meshgrid.html).  Although this is not exactly what that function is for, but if you squint at it funny, what you are asking for is exactly what it does.

Comment: That's brilliant. I knew both `meshgrid` and serialising of 2d vectors  but never considered using them in this way.

Answer (score 13):

You may use

```
a = 1:4;
b = 1:3;
result = combvec(a,b);
result = result'
```

Comment: Note that this requires the Neural Network toolbox. For those who have it it seems to be the best solution.

Comment: Like this better than the accepted solution, as it generalizes to multiple vectors.

Comment: @neuronet A late reply I know, but it's worth future visitors knowing that this is *very* slow compared to the accepted solution for large vectors.

Answer (score 4):

You could do it by replicating the matrices using `repmat` and then turning the result into a column vector using `reshape`.

```
a = 1:4;
b = 1:3;
c = reshape( repmat(a, numel(b), 1), numel(a) * numel(b), 1 );
d = repmat(b(:), length(a), 1);
e = [c d]

e =

     1     1
     1     2
     1     3
     2     1
     2     2
     2     3
     3     1
     3     2
     3     3
     4     1
     4     2
     4     3
```

Of course, you can get rid of all the intermediate variables from the example above.

Answer (score 3):

Another solution for collection:

```
[idx2, idx1] = find(true(numel(vec2),numel(vec1)));
pairs = [reshape(vec1(idx1), [], 1), reshape(vec2(idx2), [], 1)];
```

Comment: +1: I've deleted my solution, I like yours better. I've taken the liberty to correct it though, to obtain the combinations of `vec1` and `vec2`.

Comment: @EitanT: No need to reshape. Indices from `find` always should be column vectors, as well as `vec1(idx1)` etc.

Comment: I think that reshaping is necessary. Given that `idx1` is a vector (doesn't matter if row or column), if `vec1` is a row vector then `vec1(idx1)` will also be a row vector. The same goes for `vec2`.

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is the [cartesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product)

[cartprod](http://octave.sourceforge.net/linear-algebra/function/cartprod.html) is the function that implements  it. You can find it in the  linear-algebra package so you would need to do:

```
   >> pkg install -forge linear-algebra
   >> pkg load linear-algebra 
   >> sortrows(cartprod(1:4,1:3))                                            
    ans =                                                                                           
       1   1                                                                  
       1   2                                                                  
       1   3                                                                  
       2   1                                                                  
       2   2                                                                  
       2   3                                                                  
       3   1                                                                  
       3   2                                                                  
       3   3                                                                  
       4   1                                                                  
       4   2                                                                  
       4   3
```

Comment: For what it's worth, a function claiming to do the same thing is also available on the [MATLAB File exchange](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/5475-cartprod--cartesian-product-of-multiple-sets).

Answer (score 2):

You can use plain old matrix operations, e.g. in

```
x = [3,2,1];
y = [11,22,33,44,55];
v = [(ones(length(y),1) * x)(:), (ones(length(x), 1) * y)'(:)]
```

**Edit:** this is Octave syntax, MATLAB will look like this:

```
x = [3,2,1];
y = [11,22,33,44,55];
A = ones(length(y),1) * x;
B = (ones(length(x), 1) * y)';
v = [A(:) B(:)]
```

in both cases, result will be

```
v =
 3    11
 3    22
 3    33
 3    44
 3    55
 2    11
 2    22
 2    33
 2    44
 2    55
 1    11
 1    22
 1    33
 1    44
 1    55
```

Comment: That's not valid MATLAB syntax.

Answer (score 2):

As of MATLAB R2023a, you can use the combinations function to do this. Details at https://blogs.mathworks.com/matlab/2023/04/04/the-new-combinations-function-in-matlab-for-cartesian-products-and-parameter-sweeps/

```
> A = [1,2,3];B=[4,5];
>> C = combinations(A,B)
C =
6×2 table
A    B
_    _
1    4
1    5
2    4
2    5
3    4
3    5
```

The result is a table. When all data types are compatible (as is the case here) you can get the matrix like this

```
>> C.Variables
ans =
1     4
1     5
2     4
2     5
3     4
3     5
```

Answer (score 1):

Here a more MATLAB'esque way to find the combinations. This one can also be easily extended to more then 2 vectors (and also non-numerical combinations):

```
v1 =   1:  1:  3;
v2 =  11: 11: 44;
v3 = 111:111:555;

dimensions = cellfun(@numel, {v1,v2,v3});

[i1,i2,i3] = ind2sub(dimensions, 1:prod(dimensions));

combinations = [v1(i1); v2(i2); v3(i3)]'
```

Answer (score 1):

Starting from version R2015a, you can do this using [`repelem`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/repelem.html) and [`repmat`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/repmat.html):

```
>> vec1 = 1:4;
>> vec2 = 1:3;
>> pairs = [repelem(vec1(:), numel(vec2)) ...
            repmat(vec2(:), numel(vec1), 1)]

pairs =

     1     1
     1     2
     1     3
     2     1
     2     2
     2     3
     3     1
     3     2
     3     3
     4     1
     4     2
     4     3
```

This type of solution avoids the additional intermediate variables required by some of the other solutions (such as those based on [`meshgrid`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/meshgrid.html)) which could lead to memory issues for larger vectors.