# sum of k combination of vectors from n vectors

Tags: matlab

I want sum of two vectors at time from set of n vectors
for eg;

```
A1=[1 2 3] 
A2=[2 3 4] 
A3=[3 4 5]
.
.
.
An=[6 6 9]
```

I want sum of (Ai + Aj) for all values of i and j.
so if n=10 then I need all combinations i.e. 10*9/2

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way to compute it manually, assuming the set of n vectors is stored in a matrix `A`, row by row:

1. Obtain all possible pairs of indices (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7446946/how-to-generate-all-pairs-from-two-vectors-in-matlab-using-vectorised-code) for possible answers). For instance:

   ```
   [idx2, idx1] = find(ones(N, N));
   ```

   The corresponding pairs are given by:

   ```
   pairs = [idx1(:), idx2(:)];
   ```

   Alternatively, if you're not interested in repetitions (*e.g.* you don't want the sum A<sub>1</sub>+A<sub>1</sub>, etc.), you can use `nchoosek`:

   ```
   pairs = nchoosek(1:N, 2)
   idx1 = pairs(:, 1);
   idx2 = pairs(:, 2);
   ```
2. Use each pair of indices to sum the corresponding rows in `A`:

   ```
   sums = A(idx1(:), :) + A(idx2(:), :);
   ```

   Alternatively, if you want the total sum of elements for each pair of A<sub>i</sub> and A<sub>j</sub>, you can do `sum(A(idx1(:), :) + A(idx2(:), :), 2)` instead.

#### Example

Here's an example for `N = 3`:

```
A = [1 2 3; 2 3 4; 3 4 5];
N = size(A, 1);
[idx2, idx1] = find(ones(N, N));
pairs = [idx1(:), idx2(:)];
sums = A(idx1(:), :) + A(idx2(:), :);
```

The result is:

```
pairs =
     1     1
     1     2
     1     3
     2     1
     2     2
     2     3
     3     1
     3     2
     3     3

sums =      
     2     4     6
     3     5     7
     4     6     8
     3     5     7
     4     6     8
     5     7     9
     4     6     8
     5     7     9
     6     8    10
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [pdist](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/pdist.html)

```
pdist(X) computes the Euclidean distance between pairs of objects in m-by-n data matrix X. Rows of X correspond to observations, and columns correspond to variables.
```

And define your own custom metric which will just be a function that sums two vectors (although I have a feeling that `@plus` will work in your case i.e. `pdist(X, @plus)`)

Comment: It is important to note that `pdist` requires installing the Statistics Toolbox.

Answer (score 0):

Lets have a try, as I am not sure whether you want a list of vectors as output or a list of sums I will give you both.

```
A1=[1 2 3] 
A2=[2 3 4] 
A3=[3 4 5] 
An=[6 6 9]
```

First of all make sure everything is put together in a matrix (Can be automated if required, but I hope you can get this matrix as input)

```
A = [A1;A2;A3;An]
```

Now we can just use a small loop to simply work on the combinations:

```
n = size(A,1);
m = size(A,2);
nr_comb = (n*(n-1))/2;
pair = zeros(nr_comb,2);
result = zeros(nr_comb,m);
count = 0;
for i = 1:n-1;
   for j = i+1:n
       count = count +1;
       pair(count,:) = [i j];
       result(count,:) = A(i,:) + A(j,:);
   end
end
```

Now assuming you actually want the sums of the combinations of vectors you can easily get them like so:

```
sumresult = sum(result')
```

It should not be too hard to add the symmetric variation, or the case where you combine a vector with itself, but given the number of combinations that you expect, this should be what you are looking for.

Comment: Note that if you actually just want sumresult, the computation could be made more efficient by calculating the sum of each vector in advance.