# Concatenating all combinations of matrix rows

Tags: matlab, matrix, combinations

i use matlab and need to combine two 2-dimensional matrices, so that the resulting rows are combinations of the rows from the input matrices concatenated together.

I tried ndgrid, but this creates ALL possible combinations. I need the input rows to stay together to create the output.

Here is an example:

I got:

```
  a= [1 2 3
      4 5 6];

  b= [7 8
      9 10];
```

I need:

```
needed = [1 2 3 7 8
          1 2 3 9 10
          4 5 6 7 8
          4 5 6 9 10];
```

I would prefer to do this without loops if possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an adaptation of [yuk's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15907678/1336150) using `find`:

```
[ib, ia] = find(true(size(b, 1), size(a, 1)));
needed = [a(ia(:), :), b(ib(:), :)];
```

This should be much faster than using `kron` and `repmat`.

#### Benchmark

```
a = [1 2 3; 4 5 6];
b = [7 8; 9 10];

tic
for k = 1:1e3
    [ib, ia] = find(true(size(b, 1), size(a, 1)));
    needed = [a(ia(:), :), b(ib(:), :)];
end
toc

tic
for k = 1:1e3
    needed = [kron(a, ones(size(b,1),1)), repmat(b, [size(a, 1), 1])];
end
toc
```

The results:

```
Elapsed time is 0.030021 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.17028 seconds.
```

Comment: @Jennes Yes, indeed. If you still have any question about the specific usage of `find` in this answer, I'll be more than glad to explain it.

Answer (score 1):

Use a Kronecker product for `a` and `repmat` for `b`:

```
[kron(a, ones(size(b,1),1)), repmat(b, [size(a, 1), 1])]

ans =

     1     2     3     7     8
     1     2     3     9    10
     4     5     6     7     8
     4     5     6     9    10
```

Answer (score -1):

It gives the desired result but you might need something else then array_merge if you have duplicated items.

```
$a = array(array(1, 2, 3), array(4, 5, 6));
$b = array(array(7, 8), array(9, 10));

$acc = array_reduce($a, function ($acc, $r) use ($b) {
  foreach ($b as $br) {
    $acc []= array_merge($r, $br);
  }

  return $acc;
}, array());

var_dump($acc);
```

Edit: Sorry I've just noticed the "without loops" section. You can change the foreach to array_reduce to.

Comment: thx, but i forgot to say that i need matlab, and want to make use of the efficiency of matrix-calculations in it.

Comment: Sorry I missed the tags, my fault.