# How to find all combinations of sets of pairs

Tags: matlab, set, combinations

I want to generate all combinations of sets of pairs of 3 men and 2 women. There are many examples for pairing (*e.g* see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7446946/how-to-generate-all-pairs-from-two-vectors-in-matlab-using-vectorised-code)), but none of them deals with sets of pairs.

For instance, if I have:

```
Men   = {'M1', 'M2'};
Women = {'W1', 'W2', 'W3'};
```

The result I want is the following sets:

```
(M1, W1), (M2, W2)
(M1, W1), (M2, W3)
(M1, W2), (M2, W1)
(M1, W2), (M2, W3)
(M1, W3), (M2, W1)
(M1, W3), (M2, W2)
```

Thank you.

Comment: The code can be extended to any number of people. Thank you

Comment: I guess you flipped your example between 'W' and 'M' 
Where's M3 ? and how come there's W3 ?

Also, there should be only 6 pairs or else I don't understand your question

Comment: Where did "W3" come from? `Women` contains only two elements...

Comment: Yes my apologies for the flipped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually it's quite simple. To populate a set of *k* pairs, you need *k* men and *k* women, so let's find all possible combinations of *k* men and *k* women first:

```
%// Find all possible combinations of sets of k pairs of men and women
k = 2;
idx_m = nchoosek(1:numel(Men), k);             % // Indices of men
idx_w = nchoosek(1:numel(Women), k);           % // Indices of women
idx_w = reshape(idx_w(:, perms(1:k)), [], k);  % // All permutations
```

Then let's construct all possible combinations of sets of *k* men and *k* women:

```
[idx_comb_w, idx_comb_m] = find(ones(size(idx_w , 1), size(idx_m , 1)));
idx = sortrows([idx_m(idx_comb_m(:), :), idx_w(idx_comb_w(:), :)]);
idx = idx(:, reshape(1:size(idx, 2), k, [])'); %'// Rearrange in pairs
```

The resulting matrix `idx` contains the indices of men and women in the sets (first column is men, second column - women, third column - men, and fourth column - women, and so on...).

#### Example

```
Men = {'M1', 'M2'};
Women = {'W1', 'W2', 'W3'};

%// Find all possible combinations of sets of k pairs of men and women
k = 2;
idx_m = nchoosek(1:numel(Men), k);
idx_w = nchoosek(1:numel(Women), k);
idx_w = reshape(idx_w(:, perms(1:k)), [], k);
[idx_comb_w, idx_comb_m] = find(ones(size(idx_w , 1), size(idx_m , 1)));

%// Construct pairs from indices and print sets nicely
idx = sortrows([idx_m(idx_comb_m(:), :), idx_w(idx_comb_w(:), :)]);
idx = idx(:, reshape(1:size(idx, 2), k, [])');

%// Obtain actual sets
sets = cell(size(idx));
sets(:, 1:2:end) = Men(idx(:, 1:2:end));
sets(:, 2:2:end) = Women(idx(:, 2:2:end));

%// Print sets nicely
sets_t = sets';
fprintf([repmat('(%s, %s), ', 1, k - 1), '(%s, %s)\n'], sets_t{:})
```

Here the resulting array `sets` is already adapted to include the actual values from `Men` and `Women`. The result is:

```
(M1, W1), (M2, W2)
(M1, W1), (M2, W3)
(M1, W2), (M2, W1)
(M1, W2), (M2, W3)
(M1, W3), (M2, W1)
(M1, W3), (M2, W2)
```

Comment: What is the 'idx_sets'? This valuable was not defined yet.

Comment: Sorry, change it to `idx`

Comment: Yeah, This is the exact code that I want. Thank you very much. Muchas gracias!!

Comment: What if Men and Women are replaced by numbers like 1,2, and 101,102,103, which part of code do I need to change? Thanks.

Comment: The code will work for all values, not just strings. The only thing you'll need to change is the string specifier `%s` to an integer number  `%d`, in the format pattern of `fprintf`. This is just for display purposes.

Answer (score 0):

This example is working using the [FEX file allcomb](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/10064-allcomb)

```
men = {'M1', 'M2', 'M3'};
women = {'W1', 'W2'};
allPeople = [men, women];
%// Play with vector index because allcomb doesn't work with cell
[~, id_men] = ismember(men,allPeople);
[~, id_women] = ismember(women,allPeople);


%// give all combinations for men/women
setOfMenWomen = allcomb(id_men,id_women);
%// give all combinations of pairs
nComb = size(setOfMenWomen,1);
setOfPair = nchoosek(1:nComb,2);
%// give all combinations for men/women/men/women
setOfPairMenWomen = cell2mat(arrayfun(@(id) setOfMenWomen(id,:), setOfPair, 'UniformOutput', 0));
%// get ids of set of pairs with the same men twice
isDoubleMen = setOfPairMenWomen(:,1) == setOfPairMenWomen(:,3);
%// get ids of set of pairs with the same women twice
isDoubleWomen = setOfPairMenWomen(:,2) == setOfPairMenWomen(:,4);
%// We don't want to have set of pairs with twice same men or same women
cond = isDoubleWomen | isDoubleMen;
setOfPairMenWomen(cond,:) = [];

%//results :
allPeople(setOfPairMenWomen)
```

Comment: It works well but there are duplicated combinations, exactly twice.

Comment: You are right, at the moment I did not find any elegant way to avoid this :/

Until I find something best you can take the first half of the arrays setOfPairMenWomen(1:6,:) which is the exact opposite of the last part.

Comment: Thank you. But when I increase the members to 3 Men and 3 Women, 4Men and 3 Women, the number of set of pairs is supposed to be 6 and 24, respectively. But your result was different that means the result does not show all combinations. Can you fix it?

Comment: For 3vs3 I have 18 combinations and for 4vs3 36 combinations.

How do you compute your total amount of combinations ?

Comment: I used permutation,i.e. kPq, k is relatively higher number between men and women, and q is lower number. For 3vs2, 3P2= 3*2=6, for 4vs3 = 4*3*2 = 24. For 3vs3, 3P3= 3*2*1=6. This is a people pairing, if there is 1 man and 1 woman, they should be paired.

Comment: Maybe I have misunderstood but I'm not sure this relation is correct.

If there is 1M&1W the result is impossible (no pair) or I did not understand the initial request.

Comment: For me, the minimum of people is 2M&2W otherwise you can't have a pair of people.
For the moment this code sample reacts as I expect.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot see exactly what your question is. Do you search for an algorithm or an implementation in MATLAB? I will try to answer with a mathematical approach.

You might be able to solve your problem by formulating it as a [graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_theory) problem: Your set of persons is the set of vertices. Form edges by connecting all men to all women. Now find the set of (maximum) [matchings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matching_%28graph_theory%29).

It depends a bit on what exactly you want: Do you want for example the element ((M1, W1)) to be part of your solution? Then you're searching for matchings (see [Hosoya index](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosoya_index) for the number of elements in your solution set). If you want only elements where no further pairing can be added, then you only consider maximum matchings.

This might help if you extend your problem to generic non-gendered pairs: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telephone_number_(mathematics)