# How to generate unique pairs of the elements of a vector - ignoring the order of the pair elements

Tags: matlab

I found this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7446946/how-to-generate-all-pairs-from-two-vectors-in-matlab-using-vectorised-code) by @Lambdageek to the problem of generating pairs of the elements of a vector in Matlab:

```
[p,q] = meshgrid(vec1, vec2);
pairs = [p(:) q(:)];
```

However I want to generate unique pairs from the elements of a vector, let's say [1 2 3]. [1 2] and [2 1] I would consider as duplicates of the same pair and I want to ignore the order of the pair elements.

```
1 2
1 3
2 1
2 3 
3 1
3 2
```

should reduce to:

```
1 2
1 3
2 3
```

Does anyone know an elegant solution to this? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Say the length of the vectors are n, use upper triangular matrix to generate a mask:

```
[p, q] = meshgrid(1:n, 1:n);
mask   = triu(ones(n), 1) > 0.5;
pairs  = [p(mask) q(mask)];
```

Comment: Does not appear to work for vectors in general. For example: `vec1 = 1:3, vec2 = 10:-1:8` will give the wrong result, and I wouldn't even know how to use this for vectors of unequal length. (As they were in the referenced question).

Comment: Just use `vector(pairs)` as the result. As for unequal length, well, the OP says "a vector", not "two vectors"

Answer (score 4):

You can sort each row and then look for unique rows:

```
uniquepairs = unique(sort(pairs,2), 'rows')
```

This works fine even if you have more than two columns.

For your example this returns

```
uniquepairs =
     1     2
     1     3
     2     3
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is probably this:

```
uniquePairs = nchoosek(1:n,2)
```

Or, in terms of an arbitrary vector `v`:

```
uniquePairs = nchoosek(v,2)
```

Comment: As is, the solution won't generate pairs of elements from vectors. (Unless these happen to be `1:n`)

Comment: I followed @prgao using just vectors of the form `1:n`. I thought that was clear enough. But you're right, it's better to spell it out. Corrected.

Comment: There is still some spelling to do as it requires 2 input vectors (Judging from the original pair creation 1 element should be picked from the first, and 1 from the second)

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin Hmm I don't get what you mean. Why two vectors? The question says "generating pairs of the elements of a vector"