# Find all pairs of MATLAB structs

Tags: arrays, matlab, struct, combinations

I am handling structures in the form:

```
struct('num', 2,
       'w1', 0.5,
       'w2', 0.5 );
```

contained in an array:

```
array = [struct1, struct2, ..., structN]
```

I would like to know whether it is possible to find automatically all the pairs of structures, as follows:

```
[struct1 struct2
 struct1 struct3
 ...
 struct1 structN
 struct2 struct3
 ...]
```

As a reference, I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7446946/how-to-generate-all-pairs-from-two-vectors-in-matlab-using-vectorised-code) for simple arrays.

Answer (score 2):

Besides the obvious [`nchoosek` solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26591096/1714410), we can also get the indices a bit more creatively:

```
>> [j,i] = find(tril(true(N),-1));
>> pairs = array([i(:) j(:)])
```

---

The idea is to build a logical triangular matrix, and extract the row/column indices of the nonzero elements:

```
>> tril(true(5),-1)
ans =
     0     0     0     0     0
     1     0     0     0     0
     1     1     0     0     0
     1     1     1     0     0
     1     1     1     1     0
```

or

```
>> triu(true(5),1)
ans =
     0     1     1     1     1
     0     0     1     1     1
     0     0     0     1     1
     0     0     0     0     1
     0     0     0     0     0
```

depending on which order you want for the indices.

Answer (score 0):

Try the [allcomb](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/10064-allcomb).

Example:

```
a = [struct1, struct2, ..., structN];
allcomb(a(:))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`nchoosek`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/nchoosek.html) to get indices of all pairs

```
result = array( nchoosek( 1:N, 2 ) );
```