# generate Combinations from a value in matlab

Tags: matlab, combinations

How to generate the different combinations possible for a certain number
Example:

`m=2`   gives:

```
[1 1;1 2;2 1;2 2]
```

`m=3` gives:
`[1 1;1 2;1 3;2 1;2 2;2 3;3 1;3 2;3 3]` 
and so on...

using `perms([1 2])` generates `[1 2;2 1]` only

Comment: These are actually **not** *combinations* in the mathematical sense, as then `[1,2]` and `[2,1]` would be the same. Also they are not *permutations*, that's why `perms` won't work. These are really just *tuples* of the *cartesian product*. This may sound overly exact, but if you search for a solution to this problem, then the correct names will get you a lot further.

Comment: You can use [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21895344/2586922) with input `vectors = { 1:m, 1:m }` to generate all tuples ("combinations")

Comment: Or equivalently: this answer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21895583/2278029) with input `vectors = {1:m 1:m};` `combs = fliplr(combvec(vectors{end:-1:1}).')` to do the same. ;-)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Generate a matrix containing all combinations of elements taken from n vectors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21895335/generate-a-matrix-containing-all-combinations-of-elements-taken-from-n-vectors)

Comment: @Amira if an answer helped you solved your problem please mark it as accepted. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [ndgrid](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ndgrid.html):

```
m = 3;

[A,B] = ndgrid(1:m);
```

Here `A` and `B` look like this:

```
A =

     1     1     1
     2     2     2
     3     3     3


B =

     1     2     3
     1     2     3
     1     2     3
```

So you can concatenate them vertically to get the combinations. Using the colon operator transforms the matrices into column-vectors, i.e. listing all the elements column-wise. Therefore, you could use either

```
P = sortrows([A(:), B(:)])
```

or

```
P = [B(:) A(:)] %// Thanks @knedlsepp :)
```

to get sorted combinations.

P now looks like this:

```
P =

 1     1
 1     2
 1     3
 2     1
 2     2
 2     3
 3     1
 3     2
 3     3
```

Note that your question is highly related to the following, where the goal is to find combinations from 2 vectors.: [How to generate all pairs from two vectors in MATLAB using vectorised code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7446946/how-to-generate-all-pairs-from-two-vectors-in-matlab-using-vectorised-code). I suggest you look at it as well to get more ideas.

That being said the question might be a duplicate...anyhow hope that helps.

Comment: You could even simplify the `ndgrid` line, as `[A, B] = ndgrid(1:m)` is equivalent.

Comment: And as we're at it: [B(:) A(:)] could save you the sortrows ;-)

Comment: is the `ndgrid ` approach applicable to say "4-over-3"? or just the 2d-case? +1 anyway, as it is simpler and faster than mine.

Comment: I don't understand sorry; what do you mean by 4 over 3? +1 for you as well :)

Comment: @Benoit_11: As thewaywewalk is also a native german speaker, it's probably the translation problem of "4 über 3", which should translate to "4 choose 3", instead of "4 over 3".

Comment: thats what I mean knedlsep ;)

Comment: @thewaywewalk: To apply this approach to general `k`-tuples of values `1:n`, I guess this could be generalized using: `Cs = cell(1,k); [Cs{:}] = ndgrid(1:n); tuples = reshape(cat(n+1, Cs{:}),n^k,[]);`, but well, that's more than the OP asked for... By the way: I don't think your approach will work for k=3-tuples of 1:5=n.

Comment: @knedlsepp I know, that's why I'm asking.

Answer (score 2):

It's a little tricky, as `nchoosek` can not be used straight out of the box:

```
n = 3;
X = nchoosek([1:n, n:-1:1],2); 
Y = unique(X,'rows','legacy');
```

respectively in one line:

```
Y = unique(nchoosek([1:n, n:-1:1],2),'rows','legacy');
```

Comment: Nice! I think there is a typo in the 3rd line; shouln't it be `unique(X,...)` instead of `unique(Z,...)` ?