# I have any matrix and a scalar from which i want to alter this matrix consisting of only those numbers which are divisible by scalar only

Tags: matlab

I have tried using mod function but i get error of logical expression in command window. I am new to this so little help will be appreciated. I can do this with with arrays but with matrix i am getting error. Please tell me the correct approach.

Comment: What's your error? ***EDIT*** your question to add (a) your code using `mod`, (b) the full error message and (c) the line at which the error occurs. Always include these three things in your questions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `A` is your matrix and `n` is your scalar:

```
A = magic(5);
n=2;
```

Then to manipulate (e.g. multiply by `1000`) the elements of `A` that are divisible by `n`, just do:

```
idx = mod(A,n)==0;
A(idx) = A(idx)*1000;
```

Comment: I don't know why there is a down-vote, but this solution is clear and good for what the question is.

Comment: @SanthanSalai - I get random downvotes when I answer in a clear manner such as this example by Dan (+1 btw).  They're mostly done by people who don't answer questions in the MATLAB tag and are those who find these questions in the first-time user review queues.  They're under the mentality that if the OP has shown no effort, then we shouldn't answer the questions and the -1 is to discourage answering.  Me personally I don't care.  If I think the question is interesting, regardless of the effort, I will answer it as we want to share knowledge. I just don't let them bother me and move on.

Comment: @SanthanSalai - Besides which, I believe that I'll receive more upvotes than down and so they'll cancel out in the end :)

Comment: @rayryeng Completely agree. BTW this happened for me today also for [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30471358/finding-a-critical-point-in-matrix/30471663#30471663) somebody came, downvoted and went silently.

Comment: Why i get -5 for asking question?

Comment: @manroop your question was unclear and didn't include the three things I mentioned in my comment which you had ample time to add : your choice from your attempts, complete error message, line at which error occurred