# Cartesian product in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix, cartesian-product

Here is the simplified version of the problem I have. Suppose I have a vector

```
p=[1 5 10]
```

and another one

```
q=[.75 .85 .95]
```

And I want to come up with the following matrix:

```
res=[1, .75;
     1, .85;
     1, .95;
     5, .75;
     5, .85;
     5, .95;
    10, .75;
    10, .85;
    10, .95]
```

This is also known as the Cartesian Product.
How can I do that?

Comment: Actually, I found that http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/5898 this thing does exactly what I want!

Comment: You should put that as an answer and accept your own answer to close the question.

Comment: Similar question: [Matlab - Generate all possible combinations of the elements of some vectors](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4165859/97160)

Answer (score 48):

Here's one way:

```
[X,Y] = meshgrid(p,q);
result = [X(:) Y(:)];
```

The output is:

```
result =

    1.0000    0.7500
    1.0000    0.8500
    1.0000    0.9500
    5.0000    0.7500
    5.0000    0.8500
    5.0000    0.9500
   10.0000    0.7500
   10.0000    0.8500
   10.0000    0.9500
```

Comment: While this indeed is the Cartesian Product, it's not what the OP asked for. It would need an aditional step of `result=sum(result,2)` to qualify.

Comment: I don't think that's true.  If you look closely, the result matrix in the OP's question appears to be 2×9, not 1×9.  The first row is "1, 0.75" (note the space in "1 .75"), not 1.75.  This is further confirmed by the linked FileExchange script that he says does exactly the right thing.  I agree that it's confusing--I had to squint to see what was going on!

Comment: You're entirely correct on that one. I'll correct his post for clarity.

Answer (score 5):

A similar approach as the one described by @nibot can be found in [matlab central file-exchange](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/5898-setprod).

It generalizes the solution to any number of input sets. This would be a simplified version of the code:

```
function C = cartesian(varargin)
    args = varargin;
    n = nargin;

    [F{1:n}] = ndgrid(args{:});

    for i=n:-1:1
        G(:,i) = F{i}(:);
    end

    C = unique(G , 'rows');
end
```

For instance:

```
cartesian(['c','d','e'],[1,2],[50,70])

ans =

    99     1    50
    99     1    70
    99     2    50
    99     2    70
   100     1    50
   100     1    70
   100     2    50
   100     2    70
   101     1    50
   101     1    70
   101     2    50
   101     2    70
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a function, `cartesian_product`, that can handle any type of input, including string arrays, and returns a table with column names that match the names of the input variables. Inputs that are not variables are given names like `var1`, `var2`, etc.

```
function tbl = cartesian_product(varargin)
    names = arrayfun(@inputname, 1:nargin, 'UniformOutput', false);
    
    for i = 1:nargin
        if isempty(names{i})
            names{i} = ['var' num2str(i)];
        end
    end
    
    rev_args = flip(varargin);
    
    [A{1:nargin}] = ndgrid(rev_args{:});

    B = cellfun(@(x) x(:), A, 'UniformOutput', false);
    C = flip(B);
    
    tbl = table(C{:}, 'VariableNames', names);
end
```

```
>> x = ["a" "b"];
>> y = 1:3;
>> z = 4:5;
>> cartesian_product(x, y, z)

ans =

  12×3 table

     x     y    z
    ___    _    _

    "a"    1    4
    "a"    1    5
    "a"    2    4
    "a"    2    5
    "a"    3    4
    "a"    3    5
    "b"    1    4
    "b"    1    5
    "b"    2    4
    "b"    2    5
    "b"    3    4
    "b"    3    5
```

```
>> cartesian_product(1:2, 3:4)

ans =

  4×2 table

    var1    var2
    ____    ____

     1       3  
     1       4  
     2       3  
     2       4
```