# Create all possible Mx1 vectors from an Nx1 vector in MATLAB

Tags: arrays, algorithm, matlab, vector

I am trying to create all possible 1xM vectors (word) from a 1xN vector (alphabet) in MATLAB. N is > M. For example, I want to create all possible 2x1 "words" from a 4x1 "alphabet" `alphabet = [1 2 3 4]`;

I expect a result like:

```
[1 1]
[1 2]
[1 3]
[1 4]
[2 1]
[2 2]
...
```

I want to make M an input to my routine and I do not know it beforehand. Otherwise, I could easily do this using nested for-loops. Anyway to do this?

Comment: Here's the question that gave me the clue to the compact answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9834254/cartesian-product-in-matlab  (I will take credit for knowing to search for "matlab cartesian product")

Comment: @BenVoigt I [should have known it too](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19991279/permutations-of-parameters-i-e-cartesian-product-into-a-multi-dimensional-arr)!

Comment: This has been asked _so many_ times. Here are possible duplicates: [How to generate all pairs from two vectors in MATLAB using vectorised code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7446946/how-to-generate-all-pairs-from-two-vectors-in-matlab-using-vectorised-code) and [Generate all possible combinations of the elements of some vectors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4165859/matlab-generate-all-possible-combinations-of-the-elements-of-some-vectors)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get all `k`-letter combinations from an arbitrary `alphabet`, use

```
n = length(alphabet);
aux = dec2base(0:n^k-1,n)
aux2 = aux-'A';
ind = aux2<0;
aux2(ind) = aux(ind)-'0'
aux2(~ind) = aux2(~ind)+10;
words = alphabet(aux2+1)
```

The `alphabet` may consist of *up to 36* elements (as per `dec2base`). Those elements may be *numbers* or *characters*.

**How this works**:

The numbers 0, 1, ... , n^k-1 when expressed in base n give all groups of k numbers taken from 0,...,n-1. `dec2base` does the conversion to base n, but gives the result in form of strings, so need to convert to the corresponding number (that's part with `aux` and `aux2`). We then add 1 to make the numbers 1,..., n. Finally, we index `alphabet` with that to use the real letters of numbers of the alphabet.

**Example with letters**:

```
>> alphabet = 'abc';
>> k = 2;

>> words

words =

aa
ab
ac
ba
bb
bc
ca
cb
cc
```

**Example with numbers**:

```
>> alphabet = [1 3 5 7];
>> k = 2;

>> words

words =

     1     1
     1     3
     1     5
     1     7
     3     1
     3     3
     3     5
     3     7
     5     1
     5     3
     5     5
     5     7
     7     1
     7     3
     7     5
     7     7
```

Comment: when `base` is greater than 10, I don't think the subtracting-`'0'` trick is going to work right.

Comment: Why does subtracting '0' turn a string to a number? @BenVoigt Unfortunately, I'm actually using a base > 10, and it doesn't work like you said.

Comment: @iab Corrected. Less elegant but hey

Comment: @LuisMendo I chose this as best answer because it had no for-loops involved and the working was well explained. Not to detract from the other solutions, but I find this routine the easiest to understand, and it's easy to quickly tell what the code is doing.

Answer (score 5):

Try

```
[d1 d2] = ndgrid(alphabet);
[d2(:) d1(:)]
```

To parameterize on `M`:

```
d = cell(M, 1);
[d{:}] = ndgrid(alphabet);
for i = 1:M
    d{i} = d{i}(:);
end
[d{end:-1:1}]
```

In general, and in languages that don't have `ndgrid` in their library, the way to parameterize for-loop nesting is using recursion.

```
[result] = function cartesian(alphabet, M)
    if M <= 1
        result = alphabet;
    else
        recursed = cartesian(alphabet, M-1)
        N = size(recursed,1);
        result = zeros(M, N * numel(alphabet));
        for i=1:numel(alphabet)
            result(1,1+(i-1)*N:i*N) = alphabet(i);
            result(2:M,1+(i-1)*N:i*N) = recursed;  % in MATLAB, this line can be vectorized with repmat... but in MATLAB you'd use ndgrid anyway
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: Haha, very concise! +1

Comment: Well, I haven't tested it.  But it *should* work, with maybe some tweaking.

Comment: There, both ordered and parameterized!  And tested, though on Matlab Mobile so I can't easily cut+paste here.

Answer (score 0):

use ndgrid function in Matlab

```
[a,b] = ndgrid(alphabet)
```

Comment: Did you see Ben Voigt's answer by any chance?