# From ndgrid grid-representing matrices to grid points

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, grid

By using `ndgrid`, we can obtain the matrices representing the grid:

```
[Y, X, Z]=ndgrid(1:2,3:4,5:6)

Y(:,:,1) =
 1     1
 2     2

Y(:,:,2) =
 1     1
 2     2

X(:,:,1) =
 3     4
 3     4

X(:,:,2) =
 3     4
 3     4

Z(:,:,1) =
 5     5
 5     5

Z(:,:,2) =
 6     6
 6     6
```

However, there are actually 8 grid "points"

```
(3,1,5), (3,1,6), (3,2,5), (3,2,6), (4,1,5), (4,1,6), (4,2,5), (4,2,6)
```

How can I create a matrix of these 8 vectors (using `ndgrid` or not in the process)? That is,

```
3 1 5
3 1 6
3 2 5
3 2 6
4 1 5
4 1 6
4 2 5
4 2 6
```

I've seen [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9834254/cartesian-product-in-matlab), but it uses `meshgrid`, which only works for two dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

Easy. Just linearize the output from [`ndgrid`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ndgrid.html):

```
[Y, X, Z]=ndgrid(1:2,3:4,5:6);
out = [X(:) Y(:) Z(:)]
```

If you want the same ordering as in your question, use [`sortrows`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sortrows.html):

```
out = sortrows([X(:) Y(:) Z(:)])
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to straighten these 3D vectors:

```
>> vertices = [X(:),Y(:),Z(:)]

vertices =

     3     1     5
     3     2     5
     4     1     5
     4     2     5
     3     1     6
     3     2     6
     4     1     6
     4     2     6
```