# Create a matrix using elements of other vectors in matlab

Tags: matlab, vector, matrix, combinations

I have two vectors a, b

```
a=[1; 2; 3; 4]
b=[1; 2; 3]
```

And I want to create a matrix which will look like this

```
c=[1 1; 2 1; 3 1; 4 1; 1 2; 2 2; 3 2; 4 2; 1 3; 2 3; 3 3; 4 3]
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Matlab - Generate all possible combinations of the elements of some vectors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4165859/matlab-generate-all-possible-combinations-of-the-elements-of-some-vectors)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is yet another way!

```
c = [repmat(a,numel(b),1),sort(repmat(b,numel(a),1))]
```

Answer (score 3):

I have a feeling that there is a much better way, still...

```
p1 = repmat(a,[numel(b),1]);
p2 =  imresize(b,[numel(a)*numel(b) 1],'nearest');
answer =  [p1 p2];
```

---

Found a better way:

```
 [A,B] = meshgrid(a,b);
 answer = [reshape(B,[],1) reshape(A,[],1)];
```

---

Chris Taylor suggests a more compact way:

```
 [A B]=meshgrid(a,b); [B(:) A(:)];
```

Comment: Even better: `[A B]=meshgrid(a,b); [B(:) A(:)]`

Comment: I always use `ndgrid` - the output order makes so much more sense.