# How to find all permutations (with repetition) in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, permutation, cartesian-product

Suppose I have 4 letters and I want to arrange them in 3 places (repetition allowed), so I would have 4<sup>3</sup>=64 possible permutations. How can I compute and print them?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Matlab - Generate all possible combinations of the elements of some vectors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4165859/matlab-generate-all-possible-combinations-of-the-elements-of-some-vectors)

Comment: This is actually the cartesian product and is quite different from the concept of permutations.

Comment: function `perms('abcd')` returns all non-repeating permutations; it gets very slow as the input vector grows in size

Answer (score 9):

Simplifying [Amro's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4165859/1336150#4169488), you could use this:

```
%// Sample data
x = 'ABCD';                 %// Set of possible letters
K = 3;                      %// Length of each permutation

%// Create all possible permutations (with repetition) of letters stored in x
C = cell(K, 1);             %// Preallocate a cell array
[C{:}] = ndgrid(x);         %// Create K grids of values
y = cellfun(@(x){x(:)}, C); %// Convert grids to column vectors
y = [y{:}];                 %// Obtain all permutations
```

Matrix `y` should store the permutations you're after.

Answer (score 4):

How about the function [`N_PERMUTE_K`](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/11462-npermutek) from the File Exchange?

Answer (score 3):

An intuitive one-liner:

```
unique(nchoosek(repmat('ABCD', 1,4), 3), 'rows')
```

Although nice-looking, it's slow and inefficient. Don't use it for large data sets.

Comment: Nice try. While this will work for Matlab, GNU/Octave (versión 4.0.0) can't interpret it, cause `nchoosek` can only accept numeric vectors.

Answer (score 1):

Pseudocode solution:

```
Generate the (base ten) numbers 0 to 63.
Change them to base 4, which only has the digits 0, 1, 2, and 3.
Convert numbers to letters.
```

The actual Matlab code is left as an exercise for the student.