# How to extract excel column and import it to MATLAB?

Tags: excel, matlab, io

Hello I have an excel file with multiple columns up to "CD". My code words perfectly for excel files with 26 columns but after that it doesn't work.

```
[ia ib] = ismember(header, {item});
letter = find(ia)+'A'-1;
cell  = fprintf('%c:%c', letter, letter);
out = xlsread('filename', cell);
```

This code works until I get to Z:Z. When I get to AA, AB, AC,... it won't work. How do I extract the AA, CD, BG columns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't work because you are assuming that your letter for the header is only one character as indicated by:

```
letter = find(ia) + 'A' - 1;
```

What are you doing is essentially building the ASCII code for a capital letter between `A` to `Z`.  This will obviously fail if you are trying to find a header with more than one letter.  What you'll need to do is build a dictionary of all possible characters of `AA` to `ZZ`, then you can use the output of `find(ia)` on this dictionary if we exceed the column `Z` in your Excel sheet to extract out the right sequence of characters you need, then finally use this sequence of characters to index into your Excel sheet.

Referencing [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18591440/how-to-find-all-permutations-with-repetition-in-matlab), I'm going to take [Rody Oldenhuis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1085062/rody-oldenhuis)'s answer.  Therefore, construct this dictionary of all possible two characters:

```
x = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
y = unique(nchoosek(repmat(x, 1,26), 2), 'rows');
```

`y` will be a `N x 2` character matrix where each row is a unique permutation of two letters from `A-Z` (so `AA`, `AB`, etc.).  The way the code is written, it should maintain the exact ordering like how Excel does it for columns that go beyond `Z`, so `AA, AB, AC, ... AZ, BA, BB, BC, ... BZ, ..., ZX, ZY, ZZ`.  Next, we need to see whether or not the found index is between 1 and 26.  If it is, you can use your previous code.  If it isn't, then we'll do what we outlined above.  Note that I will have to subtract this found index by 26 so I can index into this character array that we created.  Assuming that `header` has all unique entries, we can do:

```
[ia ib] = ismember(header, {item});
index = find(ia, 1);
if index <= 26 %// Check if we are within columns A - Z
    letter = index + 'A' - 1;
else %// If not, we are at a column that is beyond Z.
    x = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
    y = unique(nchoosek(repmat(x, 1,26), 2), 'rows');
    index = index - 26; %// Subtract by 26 to reference into character array
    letter = y(index,:);
end
cell  = sprintf('%s:%s', letter, letter);
out = xlsread('filename', cell);
```

Note that I changed your `fprintf` call to `sprintf` as you desire to store the string representation of which cells you want to access.  `fprintf` (in your case) will print to the screen, which is probably not what you want.  Also, I've changed the variable `cell` to `ce` as `cell` is an actual function in MATLAB.

Also note that I've changed the `%c` formatting string to `%s` as the header may consist of more than one character.

Comment: It fprintf gives an error.  ====> Error using fprintf. Functions is not defined for 'cell' inputs.

Comment: @JasonThapa - Corrected.  Forgot `header` was a cell array.  Try now.

Comment: there are a total of 82 headers. header = {'hsdgsbsg' 'shsgdgd' 'hshsgdgd' sbdghd' ........'Item' 'sdhdh' 'Quantity'.......82...}; I am using ismember to find the position of 'Item'. It is around column 36.

Comment: @JasonThapa - Ah. Ok. `header` is a cell array.  I've updated my answer.  I just had to change the second line of code.  Check it and let me know.

Comment: @JasonThapa - I also had to change it to `sprintf`.  You used `fprintf` which prints to the screen...?  I'm assuming you want to store this string into a variable then use this to access your Excel file.

Comment: for ia I got column 33; for letter I got Item; for cell I got Item:Item and 9; And when I used xlsread('filename', 9) I got an error saying Worksheet '9' not found.

Comment: What I am trying to do is find the header with name Item and export the whole column to an output file that I have created.

Comment: @JasonThapa - Ahhh ok.  Let me reformulate my answer.  Hold on.

Comment: @JasonThapa - I've modified my answer.  Try that.