# Matlab - generating combinations of input and their sum

Tags: matlab, matrix, combinations, combinatorics, cartesian-product

I have to make a function that takes 3 inputs like `e0`, `e1` and `e2`. The function will have 2 outputs `x` and `y`.

`x` will be the combinations of `e0`, `e1` and `e2`. `y` will be a column vector containing sums of columns of `x`.

The following conditions must be met when creating the function:

1. inputs `e0`, `e1` and `e2` each have a single number.
2. if user doesn't enter a value for the input it set to 0 as default.
3. if user doesn't enter any input then a message that no input has been entered should be shown.

Here's an example:

```
combination pattern of X (first 3 columns):     pattern for y is the sum of x  
1 1 1                                           3  
2 1 1                                           4  
3 1 1                                           5  
1 2 1                                           4  
2 2 1                                           5  
3 2 1                                           6  
1 3 1                                           5  
2 3 1                                           6  
and so on...                            and so on....
```

So far I have only been able to do this much with `x` and `y` displayed separately.

```
function [x,y]=create(e0,e1,e2)  
switch nargin  
case 2  
    e1=0;  
    e2=0;  
case 1  
    e2=0;  
case 0  
    disp('no input')  
end
```

I googled my problem and found that combvec and allcomb should help but i cant figure out how..
Please help any answer or hint will be a great help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were on the right track with `allcomb`. You are in fact looking for the [*cartesian product*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product):

```
[e0, e1, e2] x [e0, e1, e2] x [e0, e1, e2] == [e0, e1, e2]^3.
```

You don't need `allcomb` though, as `ndgrid` can [already do this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4165859/).

Let's start with your code. It has a bug. Basically `case 2` and `case 1` are flipped.

```
function [x,y] = create(e0,e1,e2)  
switch nargin
case 2
    e1=0; % <- When nargin==2, this value is set, and you overwrite it.
    e2=0;  
case 1  
    e2=0; % <- When nargin==1, e1 must also be set to zero.
case 0  
    disp('no input') % <- use `error` instead of `disp`? If not, use `return` here.
end
```

You would then need to check that the numbers provided are not matrices. This can be achieved with something like that. (Fill in the blanks.)

```
assert(numel(e1)==1 && numel(__)___  && numel(__)___,'Input sizes are incorrect');
```

To generate the cartesian product `[e0, e1, e2] x [e0, e1, e2] x [e0, e1, e2]` you are looking for, you can either use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4166552/3139711) for `allcomb` or [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4169488/3139711) for the built-in `ndgrid`.

```
sets = {[e0,e1,e2], [e0,e1,e2], [e0,e1,e2]};

cartProd1 = allcomb(sets{:})

[x y z] = ndgrid(sets{:});
cartProd2 = [x(:) y(:) z(:)]
```

You could swap the columns of `cartProd` if you want the correct ordering.
For generating the sum along the rows, use

```
sum(cartProd,2)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Your answer helped me a lot. Now I clearly understand what I was doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

What you want are **permutations** not combinations.  You listed that `2 3 1` and `3 2 1` are different, yet if you were to make this a combination, you would consider these as being the same.  As such, I'm going to refer you to this post instead:

[How to find all permutations (with repetition) in MATLAB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18591440/how-to-find-all-permutations-with-repetition-in-matlab)

I'm specifically going to take [Rody Oldenhuis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1085062/rody-oldenhuis)'s answer.  Therefore, you can construct all possible permutations by:

```
x = unique(nchoosek(repmat([e0 e1 e2], 1, 3), 3), 'rows');
```

This will create an array of all possible permutations with `e0` `e1` and `e2`.  As such, using your example with `e0 = 1, e1 = 2, e2 = 3`, we get:

```
x =

     1     1     1
     1     1     2
     1     1     3
     1     2     1
     1     2     2
     1     2     3
     1     3     1
     1     3     2
     1     3     3
     2     1     1
     2     1     2
     2     1     3
     2     2     1
     2     2     2
     2     2     3
     2     3     1
     2     3     2
     2     3     3
     3     1     1
     3     1     2
     3     1     3
     3     2     1
     3     2     2
     3     2     3
     3     3     1
     3     3     2
     3     3     3
```

Now to finally get what you want, you just have to sum over the rows, so do:

```
y = sum(x, 2)

y =

     3
     4
     5
     4
     5
     6
     5
     6
     7
     4
     5
     6
     5
     6
     7
     6
     7
     8
     5
     6
     7
     6
     7
     8
     7
     8
     9
```

You've already written the case to handle when the user doesn't enter anything for `e0`, `e1` and/or `e2`, so all you have to do is take your code, and piece what I wrote above into your function.  It should give what you want.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. It was a great help.