# Permutations of parameters (i.e. Cartesian product) into a multi-dimensional array

Tags: matlab, combinatorics, cartesian-product

I am interested in calculating a function on a bunch of permutations of parameter values.  I want to keep it generic to N dimensions, but let me write it out in 3 dimensions to start with.  Generating the permutations is easy enough with `meshgrid`, but I can't figure out how to reshape the resulting array back to the multidimensions?  Here is a starting point:

```
%These are the 3 variations of parameters, with some values.  
params1 = [100, 200, 300];%Picking these so it is easy to correlate to the function
params2 = [10, 20];
params3 = [1, 2];

%This generates parameter_values as the cartesian productpermutations.
[vec1, vec2, vec3] = meshgrid(params1, params2, params3);
parameter_values = [vec1(:) vec2(:) vec3(:)];

%Calculates functions on the set of parameters.
%Would have a fancier function, of course, this just makes it easy to see the results.
raw_vals = parameter_values(:,1) + parameter_values(:,2) + parameter_values(:,3); 

%Rearrange into a multiarray to access by parameter indices.
f_vals = reshape(raw_vals, [length(params1), length(params2), length(params3)]) %WRONG? 

%THE FOLLOWING FAIL BUT WOULD BE EXPECTED WITH THESE PARAMETERS AND THE FUNCTION.
assert(f_vals(2,1,1) == 211)
assert(f_vals(3,2,2) == 322)
```

Comment: Maybe reshape `raw_values` to the same size as `vec1`, `vec2` or `vec3`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want [`ndgrid`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ndgrid.html) instead of [`meshgrid`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/meshgrid.html) in this case.

`meshgrid`'s syntax is `[X,Y] = meshgrid(xgv,ygv)` which causes `Y(:)` to vary fastest rather than `X(:)`.  See [Gridded Data Representation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/interpolating-gridded-data.html#bs2o5wb-1) for more details.  In other words, you are getting

```
>> [vec1, vec2, vec3] = meshgrid(params1, params2, params3)
vec1(:,:,1) =
   100   200   300
   100   200   300
vec1(:,:,2) =
   100   200   300
   100   200   300
vec2(:,:,1) =
    10    10    10
    20    20    20
vec2(:,:,2) =
    10    10    10
    20    20    20
...
```

But you want to be getting:

```
>> [vec1, vec2, vec3] = ndgrid(params1, params2, params3)
vec1(:,:,1) =
   100   100
   200   200
   300   300
vec1(:,:,2) =
   100   100
   200   200
   300   300
vec2(:,:,1) =
    10    20
    10    20
    10    20
vec2(:,:,2) =
    10    20
    10    20
    10    20
...
```

If you switch to `ndgrid`, then you get `f_vals(2,1,1) == 211` as intended.

Generalizing to N-dimensions could be done like this:

```
    params = {[100, 200, 300],[10, 20],[1, 2]};
    vecs = cell(numel(params),1);
    [vecs{:}] = ndgrid(params{:});
    parameter_values = reshape(cat(numel(vecs)+1,vecs{:}),[],numel(vecs));
    raw_vals = sum(parameter_values,2);
    f_vals = reshape(raw_vals,cellfun(@numel,params))
```

Comment: That did it, thank you.  `meshgrid` sure has strange behavior for >2 parameters.

Comment: @jlperla - Glad that did it.  The N-dim code is pretty compact, try it out.  There are some tricky cell and comma-separated list techniques at work, but I think it is generalized at least for >1 dimension.

Comment: Now that really did it!  Code has been completely generalized and passed my regression test,and I learned something about variadic functions in matlab while I was at it.