# Iterate over all subsets of a vector

Tags: matlab, for-loop, vector

I want to run code for each (nonempty) 'sub-vector' of some vector `v`. For example:

```
v=1:3;             % [1,2,3]
Pv = subsets(v);   % { [1,2,3], [1,2], [1,3], [2,3], [1], [2], [3], [] }

for s in Pv
    % do things depending on each s in Pv;
end
```

But I do not know of any `subsets(...)` in matlab. How can this be done?

---

Note the collection of subsets of a vector is not the same as the collection of permutations.

Comment: Idea: construct a matrix of dimension `2^length(v), length(v)`, and fill each row with every binary number up to that length, then use the rows as indexing.

Comment: another possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4165859/matlab-generate-all-possible-combinations-of-the-elements-of-some-vectors#4169488

Comment: getting all permutations \neq iterating over all subsets...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for ii=0:(2^length(v)-1)
    idx = logical( dec2bin( ii, length(v) )'-'0' );
    % do things to v(idx) 
end
```

Remember to check that `v(idx)` isn't empty.