# How to determine all combinations of a random number of vectors?

Tags: matlab, for-loop, combinations, combinatorics

I have n vectors with some numbers (n is a random number)
How I can determine all combinations of all numbers I have?
ex:

```
    a=0;
    for i=1:length(vector1)
      for j=1:length(vector2)
        for k=1:length(vector3)
          ... (n times)
          a=a+1;
          M{a}=[i,j,k,...];
        end
      end
    end
```

Comment: may be try http://www.mathworks.com/help/map/ref/combntns.html

Comment: I've interpreted your question to be about how best to get all combinations rather than how to execute a random number of for-loops. If this isn't what you need, please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possiblity [`combvec`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/nnet/ref/combvec.html). This function gives you all combinations of the column vectors of the input matrices. You can do the following to get the combinations of elements in your random vectors.

```
vector1 = random('Normal', 0, 1, 1, 5);
vector2 = random('Normal', 0, 1, 1, 5);
vector3 = random('Normal', 0, 1, 1, 5);
M = combvec(vector1, vector2, vector3);
```

`M` will be a 3x125 matrix where each column is one element from `vector1`, one element from `vector2`, and one element from `vector3`

If you want `n` vectors, where `n` is a random number, an alternative approach is using [cartesian product](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4165859/generate-all-possible-combinations-of-the-elements-of-some-vectors-cartesian-pr) to index into the vectors.

```
n = randi(5);
all_vectors = random('Normal', 0, 1, n, 5);
indices = mat2cell(repmat([1:5], n, 1), ones(n ,1))';
[x y z] = ndgrid(indices{:});
cartProd = [x(:), y(:), z(:)];
M = all_vectors(cartProd);
```