# MATLAB: Compute all possible column permutations of a matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix

Let's say I have an n x p matrix with columns **[a_1, ... , a_p]**. How can I use a for-loop to return all possible column permutations of this matrix (for example: **[a_2,a_1,...,a_p] etc. **)?

Comment: Check out this other question: [Generate all possible combinations of the elements of some vectors (Cartesian product)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4165859/generate-all-possible-combinations-of-the-elements-of-some-vectors-cartesian-pr)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can generate all permutations of column indices with [`perms`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/perms.html), and use the result to index into the matrix:

```
M = magic(3);              % // example matrix
pp = perms(1:size(M,2));   % // each row is a permutation
for p = pp.'               %'// "for" loops over columns, so transpose pp
    permuted_M = M(:,p);   % // matrix with permuted columns
end
```