# Find all combinations of sets

Tags: matlab, combinations

Suppose we have `2 x N` matrix in form of

```
A=| a1 a2 ... aN |
  | b1 b2 ... bN |
```

There are 2^N combinations how the row can be rearranged. I'd like to find matrix `B` containing all the combinations.

```
%% N=2
B=|a1 a2|
  |a1 b2|
  |b1 a2|
  |b1 b2|
%% N=3
B=|a1 a2 a3|
  |a1 a2 b3|
  |a1 b2 a3|
  |a1 b2 b3|
  |b1 a2 a3|
  |b1 a2 b3|
  |b1 b2 a3|
  |b1 b2 b3|
```

This is very similar to the tables used for learning basics of Boolean algebra (ai=0,bi=1).

The question may be expanded to creating `M^N x N` matrix from `M x N`.

Comment: Would this post be applicable to your cause? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21895335/generate-a-matrix-containing-all-combinations-of-elements-taken-from-n-vectors

Comment: @rayryeng If I turn double matrix into array vector of double vectors, yes. But the Lous' answer here fits better.

Comment: I understand. Good luck!

Comment: Here are some other approaches. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4165859/generate-all-possible-combinations-of-the-elements-of-some-vectors-cartesian-pr Note that the sets in your case would be `{[a1 b1], [a2 b2], ...}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
A = [10 20 30; 40 50 60]; %// data matrix
[m, n] = size(A); %// m: number of rows; n: number of cols
t = dec2bin(0:2^n-1)-'0'; %// generate all possible patterns
t = bsxfun(@plus, t, 1:m:n*m-1); %// convert to linear index
result = A(t); %// index into A to get result
```

It gives:

```
result =
    10    20    30
    10    20    60
    10    50    30
    10    50    60
    40    20    30
    40    20    60
    40    50    30
    40    50    60
```

**EDIT** by @Crowley:

Expanding the answer to the last comment:
`dec2bin` function is changed to `dec2base` with *base* of `m` (in following example we want to choose from three options for each column) and `n` columns.

```
A = [10 20;...
     40 50;...
     70 80]; %// data matrix
[m, n] = size(A); %// m: number of rows; n: number of cols
t = dec2base(0:m^n-1,m,n)-'0'; %// generate all possible patterns
t = bsxfun(@plus, t, 1:m:n*m-1); %// convert to linear index
result = A(t) %// index into A to get result
```

This gives:

```
result =

    10    20
    10    50
    10    80
    40    20
    40    50
    40    80
    70    20
    70    50
    70    80
```

Comment: This is very neat!

Comment: @dfri Thanks! `bsxfun` FTW!

Comment: This even work for `A` being cell array as well. Very neat and robust.

Comment: @Crowley Nice generalization!