# All possible combinations of the elements/vectors/list of vectors (Cartesian product)

Tags: matlab, vector, octave, permutation, cartesian-product

I have several vectors or lists of vectors and would like to make up all possible concatenations of their entries. Here is an example:

```
a1=4;
a2=[1,6;1,9;6,9];
a3=[2;7];
```

That all should result in:

```
[4,1,6,2]
[4,1,6,7]
[4,1,9,2]
[4,1,9,7]
[4,6,9,2]
[4,6,9,7]
```

I think my question is similar to this one: [Generate all possible combinations of the elements of some vectors (Cartesian product)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4165859/generate-all-possible-combinations-of-the-elements-of-some-vectors-cartesian-pr/) but I am not really able to adapt the answers to my problem.

**EDIT:**
Thank you again for the answer and corrections! As beaker already said its works like a charm in octave. Now I would also like to have it a little more flexible for an arbitrary number of `a`'s combined in a cell array (or any other structure which would fit the potential solution better). I made a work around with composing a string and then `eval`ing it. But that does not seem pretty elegant to me. Is it possible to have it more... algorithmic?

Comment: Do you mean `6,9` in the last two outputs?

Comment: @LuisMendo It's pretty safe to say "yes"...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am answering using MATLAB in the hope that the same code works in Octave as well.

---

Here's a solution based on [Amro's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4169488/3372061) in the question you linked:

```
a1=4;
a2=[1,6;1,9;6,9];
a3=[2;7];

nRows = [size(a1,1), size(a2,1), size(a3,1)];

[x,y,z] = ndgrid(1:nRows(1),1:(nRows(2)),1:(nRows(3)));
cartProd = [a1(x(:),:) a2(y(:),:) a3(z(:),:)];
```

Which results in:

```
cartProd =

     4     1     6     2
     4     1     9     2
     4     6     9     2
     4     1     6     7
     4     1     9     7
     4     6     9     7
```

It's a slightly different order than what you showed, but I think it could still be useful to you.

Comment: Works fine in Octave. :)